# how to handle foreign key constraints on a merge statement?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, constraint, merge, error-handling

I am currently doing a merge on the following table between my `test_db` (`target`) and the same table on a different database called `tablebackups` (`source`).

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[tblBCatalogueType]') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[tblBCatalogueType] 
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblBCatalogueType] ( 
    [sintCatalogueTypeID]  SMALLINT         IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
    [blnIsCurrent]         BIT                              NOT NULL,
    [tsRowVersion]         TIMESTAMP                        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT   [PK_tblProdCatalogueType]  
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED    ([sintCatalogueTypeID] asc) 
WITH FILLFACTOR = 97)
```

When I have a look at the tables that would be referencing my `tlbBCatalogueType` table I get the following list:

script to find foreign key constraints:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @referenced_table sysname 
declare @ref_Obj int 

declare @table sysname 
declare @Obj int 

select @table            = 'dbo.tblBCatalogueType'   --'tblBCataloguePriceSetItem'   
select @referenced_table = 'dbo.tblBCatalogueType'   --'dbo.tblBCataloguePriceSet'   

select @obj     = OBJECT_ID(@table)
select @ref_obj = OBJECT_ID(@referenced_table)

SELECT  obj.name AS FK_NAME,
    sch.name AS [schema_name],
    tab1.name AS [table],
    col1.name AS [column],
    sch.name AS [referenced_schema],
    tab2.name AS [referenced_table],
    col2.name AS [referenced_column]
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
    ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
    ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
    ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch2
    ON tab2.schema_id = sch2.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
    ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
where 1=1
  AND (     ( @OBJ IS NULL OR @obj = tab1.object_id) 
         OR ( @ref_obj IS NULL OR @ref_obj = tab2.object_id ))
```

[image]

this is my merge statement:

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @TranCountAtStart INT;
    SET @TranCountAtStart = @@TRANCOUNT;

    --  SELECT @@TRANCOUNT,XACT_STATE();

    IF @TranCountAtStart = 0
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ELSE
        SAVE TRANSACTION USP_Procedure_Name;

     BEGIN TRY
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------         

-- the dbo.tblBCataloguePriceSet must be run before this merge.

-- Message: The MERGE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "fk_CataloguePriceSet_CatalogueType". 
-- The conflict occurred in database "Bocss2", table "dbo.tblBCataloguePriceSet", column 'sintCatalogueTypeID'.  





                IF OBJECT_ID( 'tablebackups.dbo.tblBCatalogueType_log') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tablebackups.dbo.tblBCatalogueType_log;

                CREATE TABLE tablebackups.dbo.tblBCatalogueType_log(
                  ChangeType         NVARCHAR(10)
                 ,sintCatalogueTypeID        SMALLINT NOT NULL
                 ,DateTimeChanged    DateTime NOT NULL);



                BEGIN TRANSACTION T1

                SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tblBCatalogueType  ON;

                SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
                SELECT XACT_STATE()

                MERGE dbo.tblBCatalogueType  AS TARGET
                USING tablebackups.dbo.tblBCatalogueType AS SOURCE
                   ON TARGET.sintCatalogueTypeID = SOURCE.sintCatalogueTypeID

                WHEN MATCHED

                            THEN UPDATE SET 
                                  [blnIsCurrent] = SOURCE.blnIsCurrent

                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET


                             THEN INSERT(   [sintCatalogueTypeID]
                                           ,[blnIsCurrent]
                                )
                                VALUES( 
                                            SOURCE.[sintCatalogueTypeID]
                                           ,SOURCE.[blnIsCurrent]
                                        )

                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE

                            THEN DELETE 
                --$action specifies a column of type nvarchar(10) 
                --in the OUTPUT clause that returns one of three 
                --values for each row: 'INSERT', 'UPDATE', or 'DELETE', 
                --according to the action that was performed on that row
                -------------------------------------
                OUTPUT
                   $ACTION ChangeType,
                   coalesce (inserted.sintCatalogueTypeID, deleted.sintCatalogueTypeID) sintCatalogueTypeID,
                   Getdate () DateTimeChanged
                    INTO tablebackups.dbo.tblBCatalogueType_log
                -------------------------------------
                ;


                SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

                SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tblBCatalogueType  OFF;

                COMMIT TRANSACTION T1 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tblBCatalogueType  OFF;

    DECLARE @ERRORMESSAGE    NVARCHAR(512),
            @ERRORSEVERITY   INT,
            @ERRORNUMBER     INT,
            @ERRORSTATE      INT,
            @ERRORPROCEDURE  SYSNAME,
            @ERRORLINE       INT,
            @XASTATE         INT

    SELECT
            @ERRORMESSAGE     = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ERRORSEVERITY    = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ERRORNUMBER      = ERROR_NUMBER(),
            @ERRORSTATE       = ERROR_STATE(),
            @ERRORPROCEDURE   = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
            @ERRORLINE        = ERROR_LINE()

    SET @ERRORMESSAGE = 
    (
    SELECT                    CHAR(13) +
      'Message:'         +    SPACE(1) + @ErrorMessage                           + SPACE(2) + CHAR(13) +
      'Error:'           +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ErrorNumber)      + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'Severity:'        +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ErrorSeverity)    + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'State:'           +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ErrorState)       + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'Routine_Name:'    +    SPACE(1) + coalesce(@ErrorProcedure,'')            + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'Line:'            +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ErrorLine)        + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'Executed As:'     +    SPACE(1) + SYSTEM_USER + SPACE(1)                             + CHAR(13) +
      'Database:'        +    SPACE(1) + DB_NAME() + SPACE(1)                               + CHAR(13) +
      'OSTime:'          +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,121)        + CHAR(13) 
    )

        SELECT @XASTATE = XACT_STATE();

        IF @XASTATE = - 1
            ROLLBACK;

        IF @XASTATE = 1
            AND @TranCountAtStart = 0
            ROLLBACK

        IF @XASTATE = 1
            AND @TranCountAtStart > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION USP_Procedure_Name;
            --We can also save the error details to a table for later reference here.
            RAISERROR (@ERRORMESSAGE,16,1)

    END CATCH
```

How could I add a error-handling process to my merge?

Most probably it breaks on the delete.

```
       WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE

                    THEN DELETE
```

Here is where I should have something to handle it.

Let's keep it simple, and just say - if it breaks by a constraint violation - just don't delete the record.

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, "just don't delete the record" aside, you can change the foreign keys to be [on delete cascade or on delete set null](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973(v=sql.105).aspx). This will delete everything when you delete the parent, or set the child keys to null, respectively.

Those aren't always great behaviours. For example if a customer deleted their account you probably don't want to drop all their order history and tax invoices as well.

An ugly, hideous, but common alternative, is:

- If you know the schema isn't going to change (or you'll be the one doing it), you can just include a sub-query which will exclude those keys that you don't want to delete. This isn't too bad.
- If you wanted to get really ugly, you can use your procedure there to create dynamic SQL to do the same (putting it into a temp table and then excluding that from your results). Don't do this unless you have to.
- You could use some combination of these with an [instead of delete] trigger. This is probably the worst of all.